# How to implement multiple view inheritance in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, inheritance, view

Given `/Projects/index.ctp` and `/Person/view.ctp`, I want to make a combined view `person-projects.ctp` (displaying all of the person-projects) by inheriting both of the views. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In Cake2.x you dont inherit views (that's something for OOP and classes), you extend them:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#extending-views

Note that you can still also use elements to share/group pieces of code/markup.

Comment: thank you. let me rephrase my question:  I wanna make a combined view person-projects.ctp (displaying all of the person projects) by extending both of the views. Is this possible?

Comment: Better make it two elements and use those snippets then as you like. Views are not there to be cross-combined. It will probably only create a mess.